# Java-Error when writing to Access DB

Tags: java, ms-access

I'm trying to write some data to an MS-Access database but I keep getting "unknown source" error. Stack trace below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at SampleDB.main(SampleDB.java:15)
```

Code sample below:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SampleDB {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sample_db"); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Data_Sample (FirstName,Surname,Address) (?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,"John");
            ps.setString(2,"Smith");
        ps.setString(3,"New York");

            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();    
            System.out.println("inserted");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help in debugging the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your insert query is wrong

```
INSERT INTO Data_Sample (FirstName,Surname,Address) (?,?,?)
```

it should be

```
INSERT INTO Data_Sample(FirstName,Surname,Address) values(?,?,?)
```

Comment: Just realised that now. Guess I'm just tired and overlooking these little things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the format of the SQL statement is malformed.

should it be like

```
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Data_Sample (FirstName,Surname,Address) VALUES (?,?,?)");
```